# Title: Getting "invalid_request_error" when trying to pass converted audio file to OpenAI API

Tags: python, audio, ffmpeg, openai-api, openai-whisper

I am working on a project where I receive a URL from a webhook on my server whenever users share a voice note on my WhatsApp. I am using [WATI](https://docs.wati.io/reference/introduction) as my WhatsApp API Provder

The file URL received is in the .opus format, which I need to convert to WAV and pass to the OpenAI Whisper API translation task.

I am trying convert it to .wav using ffmpeg, and pass it to the OpenAI API for translation processing.
However, I am getting an "invalid_request_error"

```
import requests
import io
import subprocess
file_url = #.opus file url
api_key = #WATI API Keu

def transcribe_audio_to_text():
  # Fetch the audio file and convert to wav format

  headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {api_key}'}
  response = requests.get(file_url, headers=headers)
  audio_bytes = io.BytesIO(response.content)

  process = subprocess.Popen(['ffmpeg', '-i', '-', '-f', 'wav', '-acodec', 'libmp3lame', '-'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  wav_audio, _ = process.communicate(input=audio_bytes.read())

  # Set the Whisper API endpoint and headers
  WHISPER_API_ENDPOINT = 'https://api.openai.com/v1/audio/translations'
  whisper_api_headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + WHISPER_API_KEY,
                         'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
  print(whisper_api_headers)
  # Send the audio file for transcription

  payload = {'model': 'whisper-1'}
  files = {'file': ('audio.wav', io.BytesIO(wav_audio), 'audio/wav')}

  # files = {'file': ('audio.wav', io.BytesIO(wav_audio), 'application/octet-stream')}

  # files = {'file': ('audio.mp3', io.BytesIO(mp3_audio), 'audio/mp3')}
  response = requests.post(WHISPER_API_ENDPOINT, headers=whisper_api_headers, data=payload)
  print(response)
  # Get the transcription text
  if response.status_code == 200:
      result = response.json()
      text = result['text']
      print(response, text)
  else:
      print('Error:', response)
      err = response.json()
      print(response.status_code)
      print(err)
      print(response.headers)

transcribe_audio_to_text()
```

Output:

```
Error: <Response [400]>
400
{'error': {'message': "We could not parse the JSON body of your request. (HINT: This likely means you aren't using your HTTP library correctly. The OpenAI API expects a JSON payload, but what was sent was not valid JSON. If you have trouble figuring out how to fix this, please send an email to support@openai.com and include any relevant code you'd like help with.)", 'type': 'invalid_request_error', 'param': None, 'code': None}}
```